# How to free TF/Keras memory in Python after a model has been deleted, while other models are still in memory and in use?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory-management

I have a Python server application, which provides TensorFlow / Keras model inference services. Multiple different such models can be loaded and used at the same time, for multiple different clients. A client can request to load another model, but this has no effect on the other clients (i.e. their models stay in memory and use as they are, so each client can ask to load another model regardless of the state of any other client).

The logic and implementation works, however, I am not sure how to correctly free memory in this setup. When a client asks for a new model to load, then the previously loaded model will simply be deleted from memory (via the Python `del` command), then the new model is being loaded via `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model()`.

From what I read in the [Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session) one might want to clear a Keras session in order to free memory via calling `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`. However, that seems to release **all TF memory**, which is a problem in my case, since other Keras models for other clients are still in use at the same time, as described above.

Moreover, it seems I cannot put every model into their own process, since I cannot access the single GPU from different running processes in parallel (or at all).

So in other words: When loading a new TensorFlow / Keras model while other models are also in memory and in use, how can I free the TF memory from the previsouly loaded model, without interferring with the other currently loaded models?

Comment: Why error do you run into when you use multiple processes. That method seems to be the best approach here as it should clean up after itself.

Comment: @NiteyaShah I tried to put every model into its own process. The led to the issue that only one such process can access the GPU. When another process tries to access the GPU then Tensorflow throws an error. The problöem seems to be related to memory allocation on the graphics card, but I haven't been able to solve it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a Tensorflow session starts, it will try to allocate all of the GPU memory available. This is what prevents multiple processes from running sessions. The ideal way to stop this is to ensure that the tf session only allocates a part of the memory. From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth), there are two ways to do this(Depending on your tf version)

1. The simple way is (tf 2.2+)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

for tf 2.0/2.1

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.gpu.set_per_process_memory_growth(True)
```

for tf 1.* (Allocate 30% percentage of memory per process)

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

2. The other method is more controlled IMHO and scales better. It requires that you create logical devices and manually control placement for each of them.

```py
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
# Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
    try:
        tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
            gpus[0],
            [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024),
             tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)]
     except RuntimeError as e:
            # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
         print(e)
```

Now you have to manually control placement using the with

```py
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Replicate your computation on multiple GPUs
  c = []
  for gpu in gpus:
    with tf.device(gpu.name):
      a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
      b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
      c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))

  with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    matmul_sum = tf.add_n(c)

  print(matmul_sum)
```

Using this you won't run of out memory and can run multiple processes at once.

Comment: Ok, limiting the GPU memory per process might do the trick. However, in my case I don't know how many clients (and thus processes) I will have in advance. There might be 10 clients, but there might also be 25 or 50 clients. With my setup (all models in one process) this is not an issue, but how can I solve this with your approach?

Comment: Depends entirely on your client model. Using virtualized GPUs gives you limitless flexibility with what you want to provide your clients. Eventually, even with a single process, you can run out of memory. The advantage will be that instead of all other clients' processes stopping, only one will fail. As for much memory you want to allocate, the only way to be sure is to test how much your models will need. Perhaps in your frontend, you can give the option on how much GPU memory you can allow per client.

Comment: Essentially, all your clients will get not only their own process but also their own GPU(logical). This method will also allow you to scale better the day you decide you want to provide resources of more than one GPU.

Answer (score -1):

You can fork new kernels by customers. Each process will execute operations and separated environments with each other. It is safer and isolated way.

I created a basic scenario which has two parts. The main part's responsibility to start, execute and kill processes. The client part's responsibility is executing operations from the server's orders. Each client waits for orders with HTTP requests.

**main.py**

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import requests

class ClientOperator:
    def __init__(self, name, port, model):
        self.name = name
        self.port = port
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'client.py', 
                                f'--port={port}', f'--model={model}'])
    
    def process(self, a, b):
        response = requests.get(f'http://localhost:{self.port}/process', 
                                params={'a': a, 'b': b}).json()

        print(f'{self.name} process {a} + {b} = {response}')

    def close(self):
        print(f'{self.name} is closing')
        self.proc.terminate()


customer1 = ClientOperator('John', 20001, 'model1.hdf5')
customer2 = ClientOperator('Oscar', 20002, 'model2.hdf5')

customer1.process(5, 10)
customer2.process(4, 6)

# stop customer1
customer1.close()
```

**client.py**

```py
import argparse
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

# parse arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--port', '-p', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--model', '-m', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

model = args.model

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process', methods=['GET'])
def process():
    result = int(request.args['a']) + int(request.args['b'])
    return jsonify({'result': result, 'model': model})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=args.port)
```

Output:

```
$ python main.py

 * Serving Flask app "client" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://localhost:20002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Serving Flask app "client" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://localhost:20001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)


127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2021 16:31:26] "?[37mGET /process?a=5&b=10 HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
John process 5 + 10 = {'model': 'model1.hdf5', 'result': 15}

127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2021 16:31:27] "?[37mGET /process?a=4&b=6 HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
Oscar process 4 + 6 = {'model': 'model2.hdf5', 'result': 10}

John is closing
```

Comment: I like your idea, one thing to consider though: Currently in our application all Tensorflow operations are performed on the GPU (via CUDA), but there is only one such GPU in the server. For now that is not a problem, we simply limit access to that GPU for TF operations with a Python `Lock`, thus only one thread can access the GPU at a time. Is such a scenario also possible with mutliple processes instead of threads? Morevoer, would the GPU allow to run mutliple TF models from different processes at all, even with synchronization?

Comment: @Matthias you can create a queue for ordering requests, so you can run each request sequentially. You can use Kafka or any queue management library is a good solution.

Comment: But that queue would have to be in one process, so that all model operations on the GPU with all the various TF models would again end up in the same process, right?

Comment: Queue manager ensures that transactions will run sequentially. I don't know your business requirements. However, returning responses asynchronously is a good option.

Comment: I understand the use of queues, but the thing is that from my understanding in this scenario then all the processing would again end up in one process, which we wanted to avoid in order to be able to run `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`, right?

Comment: You have one GPU and you have to run one process at any time. You can use `threadLock.acquire() .. threadLock.release()`. `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` clears all session objects on kernel. Objects by customer must be created in different sessions, maybe `tf.compat.v1.Session` can help.

Comment: It really seems this approach is not an option for me. I re-created your example setup as you have described it in your answer and tried to access the GPU via TF from those different processes. As expected this is not possible, as TF does not seem to allow access to a single GPU from different processes. So as long as I have not missiunderstood this it seems your suggested approach is not the solution in my case.